# WPF Datagrid not showing values only rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to implement updating DataGrid, that has only one line and header, but variable amount of columns (which take data from different values) and values in cells have to be able to change (although only by the program, not the user). I have therefore set ItemsSource to

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>
```

and hoped for the best. The datagrid generates, shows columns that are generated by

```
DataGridTextColumn newColumn = new DataGridTextColumn { Header = header, Width = column.Width }; 
Aggreg.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

With the datagrid generated as:

```
<wpftoolkit:DataGrid x:Name="Aggreg" RowHeaderWidth="0" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Then I bind the collection to the datagrid:

```
Aggreg.ItemsSource = collection;
```

When I try the program however only blank line is shown no matter what data is inside the collection

[image]

Edit: Just to add - the problem is  mostly binding data columns to position(index) in collection, i.e. column 1 should show item in list with index 1 etc.

Comment: Is your collection a property? Do you set DataContext? Also, you need to bind DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: If you are using `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, you need to bind every column to corresponding data.

Comment: collection is the ObservableCollection. I tried setting DataContext, still ends the same. Can I bind the column to position in the Observable collection?

Comment: If I turn on Autogenerating I only get one more column called Count with number of items in the nested collection

Comment: So If I need to Bind column to corresponding data, can I bind column to List[index]

Answer (score 0):

As Miamy said there needs to be a binding for the DataGridTextColumns, but all my previous tries to bind failed. However - here is the correct syntax for programatically binding to index in Collection:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("NewList[INDEX]");
```